# Razor View ForEach in different columns

Tags: c#, html, razor

Trying the get each ForEach loop to be under the relevant columns but it is all displaying under the Name column.                                                                               .                                                                                               .                                                                                 .                                                                                .                                                                               .

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age Plus Twenty</th>
                <th>Colour</th>
                <th>Frequency</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var user in Model.users)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@user.firstName @user.lastName</td>
                </tr>
            }
            @foreach (var age in Model.AgePlusTwenty)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@age.ToString()</td>
                </tr>
            }
            @foreach (var colour in Model.TopColours)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@colour.Colour</td>
                    <td>@colour.Amount</td>
                </tr>
            }.
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

```
public class PeopleModel : PageModel
    {

        public class TopColour
        {
            public string Colour { get; set; }
            public int Amount { get; set; }
        }
        public int[] AgePlusTwenty { get; set; }
        public TopColour[] TopColours { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }
        public string favouriteColour { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public List<PeopleModel> users { get; set; }

        public static int CalculateAge(DateTimeOffset birthDate, DateTimeOffset now)
        {
            var age = now.Year - birthDate.Year;

            if (now.Month < birthDate.Month || (now.Month == birthDate.Month && now.Day < birthDate.Day))
            {
                age--;
            }

            return age;
        }
        public PageResult OnGet()
        {
            string json = new WebClient().DownloadString("my api");
            users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PeopleModel>>(json);
           
            var ages = new List<int>(users.Count());
            var topColours = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                var calculatedAge = CalculateAge(user.dob, DateTimeOffset.Now);

                ages.Add(calculatedAge + 20);

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.favouriteColour)
                    && !topColours.ContainsKey(user.favouriteColour))
                {
                    topColours.Add(user.favouriteColour, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    var count = topColours[user.favouriteColour];
                    count++;
                    topColours[user.favouriteColour] = count;
                }
            }

            var topColoursArr = topColours
                .Select(x => new TopColour() { Colour = x.Key, Amount = x.Value })
                .ToArray()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount).ToArray();

            AgePlusTwenty = ages.ToArray();
            TopColours = topColoursArr;
            return Page();

        }

    }
```

Comment: You are outputting a new `TR` element for each loop. Why do you even have multiple enumerables in the first place though, if they are related data, then it would be much better if all properties were in the same object.

Comment: Hey try adding properties in single list object and instead of creating new row everytime , use foreach once and iterate though each column to display your required values.

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting a new `TR` element (i.e. a new table row) for each loop. If you really need to keep your model in it's current form, then you could do something like this:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.users.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.users[i].firstName @Model.users[i].lastName</td>
        <td>@Model.AgePlusTwenty[i].ToString()</td>
        <td>@Model.TopColours[i].Colour</td>
        <td>@Model.TopColours[i].Amount</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is a little dangerous though. For a start, it assumes that each enumerable has the same number of elements.

However, if these values are all related data, then it would be much better if all properties were in the same object. Then you would be able to do something like this:

```
@foreach (var user in Model.users)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.firstName @user.lastName</td>
        <td>@user.Age</td>
        <td>@user.Colour</td>
        <td>@user.Amount</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks DavidG I have added the background code. Would I be able to combine this all into one object?

Comment: Almost certainly yes, but that's an entirely different question.

Comment: I seem to be getting an index out of range when using your first answer

Comment: Then the number of items in each enumerable don't match. So you may have 5 users but only 4 colours for example. What would you expect to display in that case?